# IRC in Empathy on 12.10

Tags: empathy, irc

I opened Empathy, go to accounts (F4), it takes me to "Online Accounts" where I can choose between many account types, but there is no IRC. There is face, google, twitter....but no IRC.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install account-plugin-irc
```

to get irc account . after you can sign up your irc

Comment: On Ubuntu 11.04, the IRC stuff for Empathy is inside `telepathy-gnome`

Answer (score 3):

On 12.10 it seems like you need to install [account-plugin-irc](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/account-plugin-irc/) Install account-plugin-irc package to use IRC in Empathy. Perhaps this will solve the problem on earlier versions of Ubuntu (such as 12.04) as well.